# Facebook App via PHP SDK - Redirecting back to my app's page

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

i'm trying to write my first facebook app (with only PHP SDK) and I want to automatically request permission  when users open my app.

I wrote this code:

```
$params = array(
'canvas' => '1',
'scope' => 'read_stream, friends_likes, user_photos, email, user_birthday,    user_hometown, user_likes, user_location, publish_actions',
'redirect_uri' => 'https://apps.facebook.com/myapp/'
);
$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl($params);
<script type='text/javascript'>
    top.location.href = '<?php $loginUrl ?>';
</script>
```

But the browser redirect me to my app url (not to my apps.facebook.com/myapp/ but to www.myhost.com/myapp)

Can someone help me?

Sorry for my bad english, i'm still learning it :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to echo it out:

```
top.location.href = '<?php echo $loginUrl; ?>';
```